# Jolt transform so that data of an element is the key and the value is another elements data

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I need to perform a Jolt transformation on the below example json:

```
[ {
  "name" : "foo",
  "dataSample" : "red"
}, {
  "name" : "bar",
  "dataSample" : "amber"
}]
```

I need the output to look like:

```
{
    "foo": "red",
    "bar": "amber"
}
```

so far i've managed to extract the name value as the key, but i'm lost as to how to get the dataSample value as the value for the transformed element. Here's the Jolt script I have so far:

```
[
  {
    "operation" : "shift",
    "spec" : {
      "*" : {
         "name" : {
           "*" : "&"
         }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back up the tree to get the value of the "name" field, rather than using the current value (&). This should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": {
          "@(1,dataSample)": "@(2,name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "dataSample": "@(1,name)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer more?